# SVG transformation jittery on touch, not on mouse

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I am creating a react app that uses svg, along with css-transform and matrix3d.
Within the app I am able to drag corners of an object to transform/warp it. This works fine with mouse, but as soon as I used `evt.touches[0].clientX` , it began jumping between seemingly random coordinates during the drag. The longer I hold the touch, the closer the corners gets to the touch-point.

example:
https://confident-shirley-bf53ab.netlify.app/
Press the camera, upload a random image, then click on a door.

[image: Illustration image, draggable corners]

This is the main function:

```
const handleTouchMove = (evt) => {  
    if (evt.target.localName === 'circle') {
      const offset = evt.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      const x = evt.touches[0].clientX - offset.left;
      const y = evt.touches[0].clientY - offset.top;
      if (mouseState.targetCircle >= 0) {
        if (mouseState === 4) {
          console.log('Moving door');
        } else {
          setCorners({
            ...corners,
            [mouseState.targetCircle]: {x, y}  //todo touch
          });
          const doorCorners = [
            [0, 0],
            [doorWidth, 0],
            [doorWidth,doorHeight],
            [0, doorHeight]
          ]
    
          const circleCorners = Object.values(corners)
            .map(({x, y}) => [x, y]);
          setTransformationMatrix(
            getMatrix(doorCorners, circleCorners)
          );
        }
      }
      
    }  
  }
```

This is one of the draggable circles:

```
<circle
    className="handle"
    onMouseDown={() => handleCirleChoice(0)}
    onTouchStart={() => handleCirleChoice(0)}
    transform={`translate(${corners[0].x}, ${corners[0].y})`} 
    r="7"
/>
```

Comment: You should add a full working example, if you can

Comment: I think the problem is with the `clientX`. `clientX` is the position relative the the __window__